# Why does handheld shower wall mount drip?

Tags: shower

My handhelds shower wall mount drips, and I can't figure out why. It appears to drip were the threaded pipe meets the fixture. I've applied a good number of rounds of plumber's tape and ensured it is screwed on tight to both these drop ear and the fixture. It's tight enough that it cannot be tightened any further. It's not spraying, just a constant dripping when open to the water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shower head is supposed to have an elastomer sealing washer that presses against the end of the tubing from the wall when snugged tight. You should not have to use tape or dope.

Comment: Hmm, no washers came with it. I'll try that.

Comment: Every shower head I have ever installed came with an elastomer seal ("washer") that fits in the connection end of the shower head fitting. The sealing system is exactly the same as a garden hose, but of course smaller. Look in the packaging that the shower head came in.

Comment: Use the seal from the old shower head. You may improve the performance of a used seal by flipping over to expose the other side.

Comment: Its a new build, there wasn't an old one. Reading your comment again, I think you may have misunderstood my problem. It's not a showerhead that is dripping, it's the wall-mount (AKA tap) for the hand-held so it goes drop ear -> threaded pipe -> wall-mount -> handheld.

Comment: For a new build you should be able to get the builder to send out a plumber to fix this at no charge to you.

Comment: I have no personal experience with the new style of shower where there is *both* a fixed shower head and a handheld shower so I don't understand where your leak is. But I must warn you *do not* over tighten any of these connections.  They can be damaged by overtightening. It could be that some of these threaded connections do require Teflon tape or pipe dope.